# Using find with grep and pass the result to another grep

Tags: linux, grep, find

I'm trying to use find to locate a file and the first grep will look for a pattern in that file. 
the result will be passed to a second grep like so

`find /Dime/Lock_Room/ -name CDRV.txt -type f -mtime -1 -exec fgrep  "Audience" {} \; -exec fgrep "Prime_Time" {} \;`

> I'm getting

```
1584508620604,Audience,Lunchtime/14196_135
1584508620604,Audience,Early_afternoon/8824_188
1584508620604,Audience,Late_afternoon/20124_128
1584508620604,Audience,Prime_Time/45214_3514
1584508620604,Audience,Prime_Time/55096_4206
1584508620604,Audience,Graveyard/1800_256
1584508620604,Public,Prime_Time/148351_1251
1584508620604,Audience,Graveyard/1800_256
1584508620604,Public,Prime_Time/158521_19
```

> I'm looking for

```
1584508620604,Audience,Prime_Time/45214_3514
1584508620604,Audience,Prime_Time/55096_4206
```

**PS: I'm trying not to use pipe | with find**

Comment: Why don't you search for "Audience,Prime Time" in one single `grep`? Or what is the matter with a pipe?

Comment: Your command as written doesn't "pass the result" to the second grep, it logically ANDs their exit statuses. So it finds *files* that contain both strings rather than lines that contain both strings.

Comment: exactly is there anyway to pass the previous arg {} to the next arg {} using find ?

Comment: How would that help? the `{}` are file*names*, not contents

Comment: As @steeldriver wrote, `{}` holds filenames and not contents. The only way to do it is using a pipe `|` or use a tool like `agrep` that can implement AND logic in grep. But the suggestion of @xenoid is simpler.

Comment: Does this counts as pipe? `find /Dime/Lock_Room/ -name CDRV.txt -type f -mtime -1 -exec bash -c 'fgrep  "Audience" <(fgrep "Prime_Time" $0)' {} \;`   Alternativelly you could combine find with awk instead of grep : `-exec awk '/Audience/ && /Prime_Time/' {} \;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A huge Thanks to George Vasiliou, both answers worked fine, Answer 2 is my choice.

> Answer 1

`find /Dime/Lock_Room/ -name CDRV.txt -type f -mtime -1 -exec bash -c 'fgrep "Audience <(fgrep "Prime_Time" $0)' {} \;`

> Answer 2

`find /Dime/Lock_Room/ -name CDRV.txt -type f -mtime -1 -exec awk '/Audience/ && /Prime_Time/' {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to feed the result of the first `grep` into the second `grep`.  The command in your question does both calls to `grep` independently of each other.

A suggestion would be to do

```
find /Dime/Lock_Room/ -type f -mtime -1 -name CDRV.txt \
    -exec grep -F Audience {} \; | grep -F Prime_time
```

This would find your `CDRV.txt` file (if the file passes the `-type` and `-mtime` tests) and extract all lines that contains the substring `Audience`.  This result would be passed to the second `grep` that would extract the lines that also contains the substring `Prime_Time`.  This second `grep` is running independently of the `find` command.

You could obviously use the string `Audience,Prime_Time` with `grep` directly, or, if the ordering of these two strings is uncertain, use `awk` [as you suggest in your own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/574084/116858), which would give you a bit more flexibility.

On an ordinary Linux machine running `bash`, you could also make do without `find`:

```sh
touch --date='now -1 day' timestamp
shopt -s globstar dotglob nullglob

for pathname in /Dime/Lock_Room/**/CDRV.txt; do
    if [[ ! -f $pathname ]] || [[ $pathname -ot timestamp ]]; then
        continue
    fi
    grep -F Audience "$pathname"
done | grep -F PrimeTime
rm -f timestamp
```